# How to set 2d MlMultiArray Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift, I know you can set an MlMultiArray that is init:

```
mlData = MLMultiArray(shape: [1, X], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
```

As follows:

```
for index in 0..<X {
    self.mlData[index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(index))
}
```

**But, how would I do this if the shape of the MlMultiArray was [2, X] instead of [1, X]?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc of `MLMultiArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray) shows another overload of subscript:

[`subscript([NSNumber]) -> NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray/2879231-subscript)

You can write something like this:

```
import CoreML

let X = 10
do {
    let mlData = try MLMultiArray(shape: [2, X as NSNumber], dataType: .float32)
    for i in 0..<2 {
        for j in 0..<X {
            mlData[[i as NSNumber, j as NSNumber]] = (i * 10 + j) as NSNumber
        }
    }
    for i in 0..<2 {
        for j in 0..<X {
            print(mlData[[i as NSNumber, j as NSNumber]], terminator: " ")
        }
        print()
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Was just what I was looking for.